# .NET Core Web API only works when IIS CLR Version NOT set to No Managed Code

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core web API that works fine when hosted in IIS on my local Windows 10 desktop OS.  However, when I deploy the same code to a Windows Server 2016 machine, the app pool in IIS fails 5 times and then stops the app pool.  The error in the event viewer indicates the following:
A process serving application pool 'My API' reported a failure during application preloading or service loading. The process id was '416'.  Please ensure that all application preload or service settings in the application pool are configured properly.  The data field contains the error number.

I've tried configuring the API to write out to the stdout, but it doesn't ever generate a log file.

This API was originally written in .NET Core 2.2, so I tried upgrading it to .NET Core 6 and have the same issue - it works in Windows 10 with IIS, but not on Windows Server 2016.  The hosting bundle for the appropriate version is installed on the server.  I found that if I change the app pool that is hosting my API to have a .NET CLR Version of .NET 4 instead of 'No Managed Code', it then works.  All documentation indicates 'No Managed Code' is recommended.

I did actually get it to work at one point with the app pool set to 'No Managed Code'.  I ran procmon to see if there were any failures accessing registry keys, system files or folders, etc. and did find that if I copied a few files like webengine.dll, webengine4.dll, and aspnet_rc.dll from the folders they were actually in to folders where procmon indicated it was looking for them in, it then worked.  Obviously though I don't want to be copying system files to various locations.

My guess is that something isn't installed on the server or I've misconfigured something as I got the same result when creating a test Web API project in Visual Studio and used the sample endpoints included in the default project.  Unfortunately I can't figure out what is missing or misconfigured.

I ran the JexusManager ASP.NET Core Diagnostics tool and this is the report:

```
System Time: 7/20/2022 8:01:35 AM
Processor Architecture: AMD64
OS: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0
Server Type: IIS

Scan 35 installed module(s).
ASP.NET Core module version 2 is installed for .NET Core 3.1 and above: C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll (16.0.22173.7).

Scan 91 registered handler(s).
* Found a valid ASP.NET Core handler as { Name: aspNetCore, Path: *, State: Enabled, Module: AspNetCoreModuleV2, Entry Type: Local }.
  Visual C++ runtime is detected (expected: 14.0, detected: 14.12.25810.0 built by: VCTOOLSREL): C:\Windows\system32\msvcp140.dll.
The application pool 'Test API' is used.
Pool identity is NetworkService
Please ensure pool identity has read access to the content folder D:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\Test API.
Pool bitness is 64 bit
Scan aspNetCore section.
    "processPath": dotnet.
    "arguments": .\TestApi.dll.
    "hostingModel": inprocess.
In-process hosting model is detected. To avoid 500.xx errors, make sure that the bitness of published artifacts matches the application pool bitness
Framework dependent deployment is detected. Skip bitness check.
Found runtime config file D:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\Test API\TestApi.runtimeconfig.json.
Runtime is 6.0.0.
```

I did verify the bitness and the folder permissions.  Both were set properly.

Comment: Run a report and let us know what it says, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LexLi I installed and ran the Jexus Manager diagnostics tool.  I edited my question with the results.

Comment: The report already ruled out quite a few common issues. Your last test before opening a Microsoft support case is probably to change the application pool identity as Local System and try again.

Comment: @LexLi Switching the account to Local System had the same result.  I guess I'll be opening a Microsoft support case.  Thanks for the suggestions!